# a better name-representation for mediation SEM models

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, lavaan

Each time that I wanted to build mediation models a-b-c symbols were very confusing, especially in more complex SEM relations. Therefore, I made some pre-built models (for lavaan in r) that I propose for better name-representation. Please, feel free to comment on that or to propose changes.

Note that the pre-built example may contain some errors but they are easily corrected. The advantage is that all indirect, direct, total effect are "ready" calculated, and you dont need to change anything each time that you need such mediation models in basic form. You only need to replace variables only once in Y and M models. Also they are very easily understood what they mean (at my side).

subnote: do you think that some function can automate the generation of these relations to n "X"s, to n"Med"s and to n"Y"s by simply provide as input xs, meds, & ys?

```
M=Mediator
i= item
y = y variable
x = x variable
d = direct pathX (x to mediator )
m = mediator pathY (mediator to y  )
de = direct effect
ind = indirect path
```

Example:

- ind1M1y1 = indirect path of Mediator1 on y1
- dx2M2  = direct path of x2 to Mediator2
- total2M2y1 = total effect of Mediator2 on model y1
- de_toty1 = direct effect - total on model y1 etc.

> ```
> #3x - 3Meds - 4Ys
> multipleX_Y_MEDs <- "
> #visual  textual  speed as multiple x vars
>
> visual  =~ i1a + i2a + i3a
> textual =~ i1b + i2b + i3b
> speed   =~ i1c + i2c + i3c
> # y vars ~ x vars + mediation vars
> Y1  ~ d1y1*visual + d2y1*textual + d3y1*speed + m1y1*M1 + m2y1*M2 + m3y1*M3
> Y2  ~ d1y2*visual + d2y2*textual + d3y2*speed + m1y2*M1 + m2y2*M2 + m3y2*M3
> Y3  ~ d1y3*visual + d2y3*textual + d3y3*speed + m1y3*M1 + m2y3*M2 + m3y3*M3
> Y4  ~ d1y4*visual + d2y4*textual + d3y4*speed + m1y4*M1 + m2y4*M2 + m3y4*M3
>
> M1 ~ dx1M1*visual + dx2M1*textual + dx3M1*speed
> M2 ~ dx1M2*visual + dx2M2*textual + dx3M2*speed
> M3 ~ dx1M3*visual + dx2M3*textual + dx3M3*speed
>
> # indirect effect (dx()*m) - y1
> ind1M1y1 := dx1M1*m1y1
> ind2M1y1 := dx2M1*m1y1
> ind3M1y1 := dx3M1*m1y1
> ind1M2y1 := dx1M2*m2y1
> ind2M2y1 := dx2M2*m2y1
> ind3M2y1 := dx3M2*m2y1
> ind1M3y1 := dx1M3*m3y1
> ind2M3y1 := dx2M3*m3y1
> ind3M3y1 := dx3M3*m3y1
>
> # total mediation of each Mediator - y1
> ind1M1y1tot := ind1M1y1 + ind2M1y1 + ind3M1y1
> ind1M2y1tot := ind1M2y1 + ind2M2y1 + ind3M2y1
> ind1M3y1tot := ind1M3y1 + ind2M3y1 + ind3M3y1
>
> # total mediation for each X - y1
> ind1y1x1 := ind1M1y1 +  ind1M2y1 + ind1M3y1
> ind2y1x2 := ind2M1y1 +  ind2M2y1 + ind2M3y1
> ind3y1x3 := ind3M1y1 +  ind3M2y1 + ind3M3y1
>
> # Total mediation on y1
> indtoty1 := ind1M1y1tot + ind1M2y1tot + ind1M3y1tot
>
>
> # indirect effect (dx()*m) - y2
> ind1M1y2 := dx1M1*m1y2
> ind2M1y2 := dx2M1*m1y2
> ind3M1y2 := dx3M1*m1y2
> ind1M2y2 := dx1M2*m2y2
> ind2M2y2 := dx2M2*m2y2
> ind3M2y2 := dx3M2*m2y2
> ind1M3y2 := dx1M3*m3y2
> ind2M3y2 := dx2M3*m3y2
> ind3M3y2 := dx3M3*m3y2
>
>
> # total mediation of each Mediator - y2
> ind1M1y2tot := ind1M1y2 + ind2M1y2 + ind3M1y2
> ind1M2y2tot := ind1M2y2 + ind2M2y2 + ind3M2y2
> ind1M3y2tot := ind1M3y2 + ind2M3y2 + ind3M3y2
>
> # total mediation for each X - y2
> ind1y2x1 := ind1M1y2 +  ind1M2y2 + ind1M3y2
> ind2y2x2 := ind2M1y2 +  ind2M2y2 + ind2M3y2
> ind3y2x3 := ind3M1y2 +  ind3M2y2 + ind3M3y2
>
> # Total mediation on y2
> indtoty2 := ind1M1y2tot + ind1M2y2tot+ ind1M3y2tot
>
>
> # indirect effect (dx()*m) - y3
> ind1M1y3 := dx1M1*m1y3
> ind2M1y3 := dx2M1*m1y3
> ind3M1y3 := dx3M1*m1y3
> ind1M2y3 := dx1M2*m2y3
> ind2M2y3 := dx2M2*m2y3
> ind3M2y3 := dx3M2*m2y3
> ind1M3y3 := dx1M3*m3y3
> ind2M3y3 := dx2M3*m3y3
> ind3M3y3 := dx3M3*m3y3
>
>
> # total mediation of each Mediator - y3
> ind1M1y3tot := ind1M1y3 + ind2M1y3 + ind3M1y3
> ind1M2y3tot := ind1M2y3 + ind2M2y3 + ind3M2y3
> ind1M3y3tot := ind1M3y3 + ind2M3y3 + ind3M3y3
>
> # total mediation for each X - y3
> ind1y3x1 := ind1M1y3 +  ind1M2y3 + ind1M3y3
> ind2y3x2 := ind2M1y3 +  ind2M2y3 + ind2M3y3
> ind3y3x3 := ind3M1y3 +  ind3M2y3 + ind3M3y3
>
> # Total mediation on y3
> indtoty3 := ind1M1y3tot + ind1M2y3tot + ind1M3y3tot
>
>
>
> # indirect effect (dx()*m) - y4
> ind1M1y4 := dx1M1*m1y4
> ind2M1y4 := dx2M1*m1y4
> ind3M1y4 := dx3M1*m1y4
> ind1M2y4 := dx1M2*m2y4
> ind2M2y4 := dx2M2*m2y4
> ind3M2y4 := dx3M2*m2y4
> ind1M3y4 := dx1M3*m3y4
> ind2M3y4 := dx2M3*m3y4
> ind3M3y4 := dx3M3*m3y4
>
> # total mediation of each Mediator - y4
> ind1M1y4tot := ind1M1y4 + ind2M1y4 + ind3M1y4
> ind1M2y4tot := ind1M2y4 + ind2M2y4 + ind3M2y4
> ind1M3y4tot := ind1M3y4 + ind2M3y4 + ind3M3y4
>
> # total mediation for each X - y4
> ind1y4x1 := ind1M1y4 +  ind1M2y4 + ind1M3y4
> ind2y4x2 := ind2M1y4 +  ind2M2y4 + ind2M3y4
> ind3y4x3 := ind3M1y4 +  ind3M2y4 + ind3M3y4
>
> # Total mediation on y4
> indtoty4 := ind1M1y4tot + ind1M2y4tot + ind1M3y4tot
>
>
> # total effect on y1
> total1M1y1 := m1y1 + ind1M1y1
> total2M1y1 := m1y1 + ind2M1y1
> total3M1y1 := m1y1 + ind3M1y1
> total1M2y1 := m2y1 + ind1M2y1
> total2M2y1 := m2y1 + ind2M2y1
> total3M2y1 := m2y1 + ind3M2y1
> total1M3y1 := m3y1 + ind1M3y1
> total2M3y1 := m3y1 + ind2M3y1
> total3M3y1 := m3y1 + ind3M3y1
>
> totalM1y1 := total1M1y1 + total2M1y1 + total3M1y1
> totalM2y1 := total1M2y1 + total2M2y1 + total3M2y1
> totalM3y1 := total1M3y1 + total2M3y1 + total3M3y1
> totaly1   := totalM1y1  + totalM2y1  + totalM3y1
>
>
> # total effect on y2
> total1M1y2 := m1y2 + ind1M1y2
> total2M1y2 := m1y2 + ind2M1y2
> total3M1y2 := m1y2 + ind3M1y2
> total1M2y2 := m2y2 + ind1M2y2
> total2M2y2 := m2y2 + ind2M2y2
> total3M2y2 := m2y2 + ind3M2y2
> total1M3y2 := m3y2 + ind1M3y2
> total2M3y2 := m3y2 + ind2M3y2
> total3M3y2 := m3y2 + ind3M3y2
>
> totalM1y2 := total1M1y2 + total2M1y2 + total3M1y2
> totalM2y2 := total1M2y2 + total2M2y2 + total3M2y2
> totalM3y2 := total1M3y2 + total2M3y2 + total3M3y2
> totaly2   := totalM1y2  + totalM2y2  + totalM3y2
>
> # total effect on y3
> total1M1y3 := m1y3 + ind1M1y3
> total2M1y3 := m1y3 + ind2M1y3
> total3M1y3 := m1y3 + ind3M1y3
> total1M2y3 := m2y3 + ind1M2y3
> total2M2y3 := m2y3 + ind2M2y3
> total3M2y3 := m2y3 + ind3M2y3
> total1M3y3 := m3y3 + ind1M3y3
> total2M3y3 := m3y3 + ind2M3y3
> total3M3y3 := m3y3 + ind3M3y3
>
> totalM1y3 := total1M1y3 + total2M1y3 + total3M1y3
> totalM2y3 := total1M2y3 + total2M2y3 + total3M2y3
> totalM3y3 := total1M3y3 + total2M3y3 + total3M3y3
> totaly3   := totalM1y3  + totalM2y3  + totalM3y3
>
>
> # total effect on y4
> total1M1y4 := m1y4 + ind1M1y4
> total2M1y4 := m1y4 + ind2M1y4
> total3M1y4 := m1y4 + ind3M1y4
> total1M2y4 := m2y4 + ind1M2y4
> total2M2y4 := m2y4 + ind2M2y4
> total3M2y4 := m2y4 + ind3M2y4
> total1M3y4 := m3y4 + ind1M3y4
> total2M3y4 := m3y4 + ind2M3y4
> total3M3y4 := m3y4 + ind3M3y4
>
> totalM1y4 := total1M1y4 + total2M1y4 + total3M1y4
> totalM2y4 := total1M2y4 + total2M2y4 + total3M2y4
> totalM3y4 := total1M3y4 + total2M3y4 + total3M3y4
> totaly4   := totalM1y4  + totalM2y4  + totalM3y4
>
> # direct effects
> de_toty1 := d1y1 + d2y1 + d3y1
> de_toty2 := d1y2 + d2y2 + d3y2
> de_toty3 := d1y3 + d2y3 + d3y3
> de_toty4 := d1y4 + d2y4 + d3y4
>
> # general total of whole model
> tot_whole := totaly1  + totaly2  + totaly3  + totaly4
> ind_whole := indtoty1 + indtoty2 + indtoty3 + indtoty4
> de_whole  := de_toty1 + de_toty2 + de_toty3 + de_toty4
> "
> ```

and

> ```
> #2X - 3Meds - 4Ys 
> multipleX_Y_MEDs <-"
> #visual  textual  speed as multiple x vars
>
> visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
> textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
>
> Y1  ~ d1y1*visual + d2y1*textual +  m1y1*M1 + m2y1*M2 + m3y1*M3
> Y2  ~ d1y2*visual + d2y2*textual +  m1y2*M1 + m2y2*M2 + m3y2*M3
> Y3  ~ d1y3*visual + d2y3*textual +  m1y3*M1 + m2y3*M2 + m3y3*M3
> Y4  ~ d1y4*visual + d2y4*textual +  m1y4*M1 + m2y4*M2 + m3y4*M3
>
> M1 ~ dx1M1*visual + dx2M1*textual 
> M2 ~ dx1M2*visual + dx2M2*textual 
> M3 ~ dx1M3*visual + dx2M3*textual 
>
> # indirect effect (dx()*m) - y1
> ind1M1y1 := dx1M1*m1y1
> ind2M1y1 := dx2M1*m1y1
> ind3M1y1 := dx3M1*m1y1
> ind1M2y1 := dx1M2*m2y1
> ind2M2y1 := dx2M2*m2y1
> ind3M2y1 := dx3M2*m2y1
> ind1M3y1 := dx1M3*m3y1
> ind2M3y1 := dx2M3*m3y1
> ind3M3y1 := dx3M3*m3y1
>
> # total mediation of each Mediator - y1
> ind1M1y1tot := ind1M1y1 + ind2M1y1 + ind3M1y1
> ind1M2y1tot := ind1M2y1 + ind2M2y1 + ind3M2y1
> ind1M3y1tot := ind1M3y1 + ind2M3y1 + ind3M3y1
>
> # total mediation for each X - y1
> ind1y1x1 := ind1M1y1 +  ind1M2y1 + ind1M3y1
> ind2y1x2 := ind2M1y1 +  ind2M2y1 + ind2M3y1
> ind3y1x3 := ind3M1y1 +  ind3M2y1 + ind3M3y1
>
> # Total mediation on y1
> indtoty1 := ind1M1y1tot + ind1M2y1tot + ind1M3y1tot
>
>
> # indirect effect (dx()*m) - y2
> ind1M1y2 := dx1M1*m1y2
> ind2M1y2 := dx2M1*m1y2
> ind1M2y2 := dx1M2*m2y2
> ind2M2y2 := dx2M2*m2y2
> ind1M3y2 := dx1M3*m3y2
> ind2M3y2 := dx2M3*m3y2
>
>
> # total mediation of each Mediator - y2
> ind1M1y2tot := ind1M1y2 + ind2M1y2 
> ind1M2y2tot := ind1M2y2 + ind2M2y2 
> ind1M3y2tot := ind1M3y2 + ind2M3y2
>
> # total mediation for each X - y2
> ind1y2x1 := ind1M1y2 +  ind1M2y2 + ind1M3y2
> ind2y2x2 := ind2M1y2 +  ind2M2y2 + ind2M3y2
>
> # Total mediation on y2
> indtoty2 := ind1M1y2tot + ind1M2y2tot + ind1M3y2tot
>
>
> # indirect effect (dx()*m) - y3
> ind1M1y3 := dx1M1*m1y3
> ind2M1y3 := dx2M1*m1y3
> ind1M2y3 := dx1M2*m2y3
> ind2M2y3 := dx2M2*m2y3
> ind1M3y3 := dx1M3*m3y3
> ind2M3y3 := dx2M3*m3y3
>
>
> # total mediation of each Mediator - y3
> ind1M1y3tot := ind1M1y3 + ind2M1y3
> ind1M2y3tot := ind1M2y3 + ind2M2y3 
> ind1M3y3tot := ind1M3y3 + ind2M3y3 
>
> # total mediation for each X - y3
> ind1y3x1 := ind1M1y3 +  ind1M2y3 + ind1M3y3
> ind2y3x2 := ind2M1y3 +  ind2M2y3 + ind2M3y3
>
> # Total mediation on y3
> indtoty3 := ind1M1y3tot + ind1M2y3tot + ind1M3y3tot
>
>
> # indirect effect (dx()*m) - y4
> ind1M1y4 := dx1M1*m1y4
> ind2M1y4 := dx2M1*m1y4
> ind1M2y4 := dx1M2*m2y4
> ind2M2y4 := dx2M2*m2y4
> ind1M3y4 := dx1M3*m3y4
> ind2M3y4 := dx2M3*m3y4
>
> # total mediation of each Mediator - y4
> ind1M1y4tot := ind1M1y4 + ind2M1y4
> ind1M2y4tot := ind1M2y4 + ind2M2y4 
> ind1M3y4tot := ind1M3y4 + ind2M3y4
>
> # total mediation for each X - y4
> ind1y4x1 := ind1M1y4 +  ind1M2y4 + ind1M3y4
> ind2y4x2 := ind2M1y4 +  ind2M2y4 + ind2M3y4
>
> # Total mediation on y4
> indtoty4 := ind1M1y4tot + ind1M2y4tot + ind1M3y4tot
>
>
> # total effect on y1
> total1M1y1 := m1y1 + ind1M1y1
> total2M1y1 := m1y1 + ind2M1y1
> total1M2y1 := m2y1 + ind1M2y1
> total2M2y1 := m2y1 + ind2M2y1
> total1M3y1 := m3y1 + ind1M3y1
> total2M3y1 := m3y1 + ind2M3y1
>
> totalM1y1 := total1M1y1 + total2M1y1
> totalM2y1 := total1M2y1 + total2M2y1 
> totalM3y1 := total1M3y1 + total2M3y1
> totaly1   := totalM1y1  + totalM2y1  + totalM3y1
>
>
> # total effect on y2
> total1M1y2 := m1y2 + ind1M1y2
> total2M1y2 := m1y2 + ind2M1y2
> total1M2y2 := m2y2 + ind1M2y2
> total2M2y2 := m2y2 + ind2M2y2
> total1M3y2 := m3y2 + ind1M3y2
> total2M3y2 := m3y2 + ind2M3y2
>
> totalM1y2 := total1M1y2 + total2M1y2 
> totalM2y2 := total1M2y2 + total2M2y2
> totalM3y2 := total1M3y2 + total2M3y2
> totaly2   := totalM1y2  + totalM2y2  + totalM3y2
>
> # total effect on y3
> total1M1y3 := m1y3 + ind1M1y3
> total2M1y3 := m1y3 + ind2M1y3
> total1M2y3 := m2y3 + ind1M2y3
> total2M2y3 := m2y3 + ind2M2y3
> total1M3y3 := m3y3 + ind1M3y3
> total2M3y3 := m3y3 + ind2M3y3
>
> totalM1y3 := total1M1y3 + total2M1y3 
> totalM2y3 := total1M2y3 + total2M2y3 
> totalM3y3 := total1M3y3 + total2M3y3
> totaly3   := totalM1y3  + totalM2y3  + totalM3y3
>
>
> # total effect on y4
> total1M1y4 := m1y4 + ind1M1y4
> total2M1y4 := m1y4 + ind2M1y4
> total1M2y4 := m2y4 + ind1M2y4
> total2M2y4 := m2y4 + ind2M2y4
> total1M3y4 := m3y4 + ind1M3y4
> total2M3y4 := m3y4 + ind2M3y4
>
> totalM1y4 := total1M1y4 + total2M1y4
> totalM2y4 := total1M2y4 + total2M2y4 
> totalM3y4 := total1M3y4 + total2M3y4 
> totaly4   := totalM1y4  + totalM2y4  + totalM3y4
>
> # direct effects
> de_toty1 := d1y1 + d2y1 
> de_toty2 := d1y2 + d2y2 
> de_toty3 := d1y3 + d2y3 
> de_toty4 := d1y4 + d2y4 
>
> # general total of whole model
> tot_whole := totaly1  + totaly2  + totaly3  + totaly4
> ind_whole := indtoty1 + indtoty2 + indtoty3 + indtoty4
> de_whole := de_toty1 + de_toty2 + de_toty3 + de_toty4
> "
> ```